# Laravel4 get section array in Controller/Router layer from a Blade template

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I need your help.

I've just found out that the class [\Illuminate\View\Environment](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.Environment.html) has a protected array [$sections](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.Environment.html#%24sections) and a method to get it getSections() but it returns an empty array.

Here's how I tried to get it:

```
$view = View::make('pages');
$env = $view->getEnvironment();
$env->make('pages');

print($env->getSections());
```

And the result is `Array( )`

Where did I go wrong? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you call `$env->make('pages')`, the view isn't immediately processed. It's only processed when the [`render`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.View.html#70-91) method on the $view object is called, which is done automatically when you return it as a response, via the [`__toString()`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.View.html#312-315) method. The problem, though is that just after the page is rendered, still inside the `render` method, the [`$sections` variable is cleared](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.Environment.html#473-478), using the [`flushSections`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.View.html#88) method. So you actually never have access to it.

You could try to fool it if you call the [`incrementRender`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.View.Environment.html#485-488) method before making the view, then make and render the view, get the sections and then finally `decrementRender()` and `flushSections()`, but this could bring unexpected results. Something like this:

```
// Fool it
$env->incrementRender();
$env->make('pages')->render();

$sections = $env->getSections();

// Clear it
$env->decrementRender();
$env->flushSections();
```

Comment: I love you dude. I was supposing that flushSections() was the "problem" but don't know how to avoid it.

THANK YOU SO MUCH. Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome, =D. By the way, there are probably better ways to access the `$env` object than making a view and getting the object from the view. Something like `$app['env']`, maybe,

Comment: Dunno that, but I'm sure that accessing to sections from the View is useful, so I created a pull request https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/2710

Comment: It probably is. Good luck with the PR.